# Renaming app doesn't change the schema

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4.5

I have renamed my app.I could do it successfully.But I found that renaming it doesn't change the `schema`.It was the prevoius one.Now I want to submit the app.`Is renaming schema neccasary or can I submit with the old schema.??`

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema won't get change and no need to worry about schema. It will be initial project name only. You just change the name in .plist that is enough.